# didBecomeActive posts a notification, my view controller never hears it

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsnotificationcenter, appdelegate

App delegate:

```
- (void)applicationDidBecomeActive:(UIApplication *)application {
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:APP_REFRESH_NOTIFICATION object:nil];
}
```

In my view controller:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(doStuff) postNotificationName:APP_REFRESH_NOTIFICATION object:self];
}
```

`- (void)doStuff` never gets called. Why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume that you've typed your question incorrectly and you'd meant to write `addObserver:selector:name:object:`, instead of `addObserver:selector: postNotificationName:object:` (such method doesn't exist).

In the documentation of `- (void)addObserver:(id)notificationObserver selector:(SEL)notificationSelector name:(NSString *)notificationName object:(id)notificationSender`
we can read:

> notificationSender
>
> The object whose notifications the observer wants
>   to receive; that is, only notifications sent by this sender are
>   delivered to the observer. If you pass nil, the notification center
>   doesn’t use a notification’s sender to decide whether to deliver it to
>   the observer.

So in your case, as you're passing `object:nil` in `postNotificationName:object:`, you also have to set `object:nil` in `addObserver:selector:name:object:`.

According to the documentation you also should replace the method `doStuff` with:

```
- (void)doStuff:(NSNotification *)notification
```

and use `@selector(doStuff:)` in `addObserver:selector:name:object:`.

Answer (score 1):

You're passing `self` as the `object` parameter to `addObserver:selector:name:object:`, but `doStuff` doesn't accept any parameters, so the method call fails (silently). Your `viewDidLoad` should look like this:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                             selector:@selector(doStuff)
                                                 name:APP_REFRESH_NOTIFICATION
                                               object:nil];
}
```

Comment: I'm surprised that failed silently. Thanks.

Comment: @quantumpotato: this answer solved your problem, but it gives an incorrect explanation. Please see my answer to learn a reason of why it happened.

Answer (score 0):

You're app delegate is posting a notification when the app becomes active, but your view controller isn't subscribing to that until its view gets loaded. If your app delegate is creating your view controller and loading it (which is probable) then your controller doesn't even exist at the time the notification is posted, which is why it isn't receiving it. If you use a storyboard, and that controller is the entry point in the storyboard, AND you use the info.plist for your app to set that storyboard as the main interface, then it will have already instantiated the controller and loaded its view by the time `-applicationDidBecomeActive:` is called, solving your problem.